# Uploading audio files on s3 from kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-s3

I have created a testing-bucket (public access on) by following [this](https://github.com/keithweaver/python-aws-s3/).
Now I am able to successfully upload using the method given in above link with python script but I am not able to do the same from Kotlin app.

Python code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = ********
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ***********
BUCKET_NAME = ********

data = open('bitmoji.png', 'rb')
data = open('b_f_a0008.wav', 'rb')

s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='b_f_a0008.wav', Body=data)

print ("Done")
```

Kotlin code:

```
private fun upload() {
        val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey))
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2))

        val transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
            .context(context)
            .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().configuration)
            .s3Client(s3Client)
            .build()

        val transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(awsBucketName, "test.mp3", File(filePath))

        transferObserver.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(id: Int, bytesCurrent: Long, bytesTotal: Long) {
                activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                    activity!!.showToast(Constants.TOAST_UPLOAD_SUCCESS + bytesTotal.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState?) {
                activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                    activity!!.showToast(Constants.TOAST_UPLOAD_SUCCESS + state?.name)
                }
            }

            override fun onError(id: Int, ex: Exception?) {
                activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                    activity!!.showToast(Constants.TOAST_EXCEPTION + ex?.message)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

println(transferObserver.absoluteFilePath) -> /storage/emulated/0/26-Dec-2019 4:22:49 PM.mp3
println(transferObserver.bytesTotal) -> 4750

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works

```
private fun uploadToS3() {
        val credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey)
        val transferManager = TransferManager(credentials)
        val upload = transferManager.upload(awsBucketName, filename, File(filePath))
        val uploadResult = upload.waitForUploadResult()

        while (!upload.isDone){
            val bytesTransferred = upload.progress.bytesTransferred
            println(bytesTransferred.toString())
            Thread.sleep(200)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since this solution is deprecated in java, I am still looking for a correction in the solution presented in the question?